# how do I show n json items every x seconds using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON object `items` which has few items that I want to show 2 of them every 2 seconds. How would I do that? So, it displays items in `division1` every few seconds instead of showing all at once. Eg. get all items every 5 seconds and show 4 items every second for 20 items.

```
<table id="division1" >
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Score</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>



function render_items(division){
    var tablebody ="";
        $.each(division.items, function (i,item){
            var tablerow ="<tr>"
                +"<td>"+item.name+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+item.score+"</td>"
                +"</tr>";
            tablebody = tablebody+tablerow;
            
           //$('#test').append(division.name+' '+i+' '+robot.name+'<br>');
        }
        );
        $('#'+division.name+" tbody").html(tablebody);  
}

function poll(){
    $.post("data.php", {getvalues: 0}, 
    function (data, status){
        $.each (data.divisions, function(i,division){
            render_items(division);     
            
        }); 
    },
    'json'
    );
    setTimeout('poll()',5000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    poll();
     
}
```

Comment: Be a little more clear about what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to display items in separate tables (called divisions here) but I want to show 3 or 4 items at a time and then cycle through them. i.e., 0 through 2, 3 through 5... and so on (if 3 is chosen). The full input is obtained every 10 seconds, and these divisions update every second or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would probably be simplest to hide all the rows, then show a range of them every second with something like:

```
function startShow(table) {
    var index = 0;
    var trs = table.find("tbody tr");
    function update() {
        if (index >= trs.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
        trs.hide().slice(index, index + 4).show();
        index += 4;
        setTimeout(update, 1000);
    }
    update();
}
```

and then call it with

```
startShow($("#division1"));
```

Comment: thanks, that works. Do you have any idea how I wound modify that for many table names (in a somewhat clean way)?

Comment: updated it to work with multiple tables, also a little cleaner now.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout can take a function as the first argument, it can then take advantage of closure vars to keep track of the data and the count.